# Remove whole FullCalendar instance

Tags: fullcalendar

I would like to remove (not destroy as this will set the default values) a FullCalendar instance and create it back. I use:

```
$('#calendar').html('');
```

After this, recreating the calendar using

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
...
```

won't work.

What I try to do by this is change the value for "slotDuration" and "snapDuration" after creation. If there is such a method, this will help me also. No documentation about this.

Regards,

Comment: Almost certainly no need to re-create the calendar. You can set most options as described here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/dynamic_options/

Answer (score 1):

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/te7tp5vb/). You should destroy the calendar first.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      weekNumbers: true
});


$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'destroy' );

$('#calendar').html('');


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      weekNumbers: true
});
```

Comment: It looks like the following isn't required:

    $('#calendar').html('');

Answer (score 0):

It looks like destroy works, which means the documentation statement is wrong:

```
Restores the element to the state before FullCalendar was initialized.
```